# Transaction to Smart Contract runs out of gas on Ropsten but not on Rinkeby

Tags: contract-debugging, ropsten, rinkeby, out-of-gas

the following execution of my smart contract function runs out of Gas on the Ropsten network, but works fine on Rinkeby, do you have an idea why this happens?

```
struct vehicleData{
        string status;
        uint timestamp;
        string mileage;
        string gps_position;
        string soc_relative;
        uint soc_absolute;
        string sessionId;
    }

    mapping(string => vehicleData) private data;

    function setVehicleData(string memory vin, string memory status, uint timestamp, string memory mileage, string memory gps_position, string memory soc_relative, uint soc_absolute, string memory sessionId) public{
        data[vin] = vehicleData(status,timestamp,mileage,gps_position,soc_relative,soc_absolute,sessionId);
    }
```

this is what I do in my Javascript Code:

```
const gasLimit = 100000;
const gasPrice = '2';
    const txObject = {
                nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txcount),
                gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
                gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(gasPrice, 'gwei')),
                to: storeAndCheckAddress,
                data: contractStoreAndCheck.methods.setVehicleData(vin, status, timestamp, mileage, gps, soc_relative, soc_absolute, sessionId).encodeABI()
            }
            const tx = new Tx(txObject)
            //sign transaction with private key from sender
            tx.sign(privateKey)

            const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
            const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

            //send tx
            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw,function(error,result){if(!error){return result}else{console.log(error)}});
```

Success on Rinkeby:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x86c3cfc3a5fb058810cc1854b6231b51224346e9fdd2ef835b336dff0e3796a4

Failure on Ropsten:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd48a369d549b8248383f5bd4bcf937cd1c727b6393bf2e7609ae6013258b11a6

Comment: The code is different between the two, so that seems like a more likely culprit than a difference between the networks (though that's also possible).

Comment: I did check the code with a text diff tool and it is the same.. where have you spotted a difference?

Comment: `mileage` is a `string` in Ropsten and `uint` in Rinkeby.

Comment: Thank you so much - I would have checked for ages. Deployed a new contract to all networks, but forgot to change the address for Rinkeby in the Code. Somehow for my text comparison I used the new contract, thats why i didn't see the difference.

Comment: Now both run out of gas - do you see why that can be the case?

Comment: Can you share links to the new transactions?

Comment: My first guess would be that the ABI you're using doesn't match up with the current deployed code, so the transaction data is bogus (e.g. sending a `uint256` where a `string` is expected).

Comment: I just tried with Rinkeby now, since the Error seems to be the same for both networks: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xcc391f94ddd12f8213a12a7f0320eb48a4a1f010577cacea7fd26d50a79d9b5a

Comment: I updated the ABI but I'm still running out of gas. This is my contract call: {storeVehicleData("start charging",
        12, "0x1234", "123452", "123.324,123.654", "65", 123, "sessionId")}

Comment: Definitely looks like an ABI mismatch. The call is to a function that doesn't exist in the current contract. Specifically, the call has a `uint256` `mileage` parameter, but the code doesn't have a function with that signature.